# What determines your spirit guide?

Tags: myst-4-revelation

In Myst IV, what determines your spirit guide? I'm on my second play-through and I got Water *again* so I was wondering how it can be changed? Just to be clear -- I know what to do after you get your spirit guide and what the spirit guide affects, but I want to find out what choices in the game lead to the protectors giving you a certain spirit guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explanation based on information from [ubi forums](http://forums.ubi.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/580100736/m/6091055978?r=5931099978#5931099978) and [mystlore](https://web.archive.org/web/20120330092817/http://en.mystlore.com/wiki/Spirit_guide):

Score is a number between 0 and 3, starting at 1. It determines which spirit guide you'll get and is affected by following events (most of which increase it):

In Tomahna:

- Take a photo on the monorail: 0.1
- Finish the sound puzzle with Atrus: 0.1
- See Yeesha's gecko: 0.1
- Watch Yeesha play her flute: 0.1
- Contact Atrus with the crystal viewer: 0.1

Using linking books:

- Link to both Haven and Spire from Tomahna: 0.125
- Link to Tomahna from both Haven and Spire: 0.125
- Link to Serenia from Tomahna: 0.125
- Link to Tomahna from Serenia: 0.125

Other actions:

- Spend time in the game: 0.5 total for 20 hours (0.0004 per minute)
- Use the Amulet: 0.5 total for all 101 flashbacks (0.0050 per flashback)
- Use the zip feature: -0.5 total for 30 uses (-0.0167 per use)
- Use the hint map: -0.5 total for 25 uses (-0.02 per use)

How score is mapped to title, description and spirit guide you get:

- Child of Fire: 0 to 1

  Drawn by the excitement of new experiences, always seeking adventure over stasis. Sometimes your desire to succeed makes you miss the deeper meaning but you always find the answers you seek when you really want them.
- Child of Wind: 1 to 2

  Attracted by challenge and diversity. Always moving swiftly to the heart of the matter yet willing to take the time needed to understand it.
- Child of Water: 2 to 3

  You appreciate the beauty and richness of life around you. You are confident in your ability to succeed but willing to seek help when answers seem elusive.

Comment: So the answer is "play badly"?

Comment: Here is a more detailed summary: https://web.archive.org/web/20120330092817/http://en.mystlore.com/wiki/Spirit_guide ; According to this, the above list is nearly correct, except that you start at 1 and you actually deduct points for using zip and hint map. So to get fire, you need to make at least some use of zip and/or hint.

Answer (score 0):

I once read in an older guide that your stance towards Yeesha in the beginning of the game dictated what spirit you got. There are, apparently, two "key points" where you'd be able to "change" your spirit guide. It seems that, by default, your spirit is set to water, just like Yeesha's, unless you trigger at least one of the two cutscenes below:

1. When you reach Catherine's lab, there's an experiment Yeesha's conducting with her mother involving trapped firefly-like things. If you free them and she comes and sees it, she gets angry at you, which would make you get a fire spirit later on.
2. (seems to override 1) If you listen to Yeesha practicing her instrument (interestingly, an ocarina-like thing she uses to play one of Haven's themes) by the family tree, you'd get a wind spirit guide.

When I played it, I'd always get wind (I always went downstairs to listen to her), but I need to play it again to confirm it.

Answer (score -6):

If you burn through the game as swift as a blaze, a Fire spirit lives within

If your feet beneath glide along and kick up a breeze, a Wind spirit lives within

If instead, you enjoy the game, stop to rest or view or enjoy, a Water spirit lives within

Honestly, it's the three different styles of play

Fires of Gryffindor [DPS] - You want to get through as quickly as possible. You aren't concerned about the beauty of the worlds or backstory or exploration. You're probably using a Guide Book to tear through

Winds of Ravenclaw [TANK] - You may have watched some of the Amulet Memories, but probably not many. You haven't quite stopped to smell the flowers or appreciate the sounds of the creatures of Serenia. Swift of mind, the puzzles took you no time. A bit of a challenge, but somewhat like chess to checkers.

Waters of Hufflepuff [HEALER] - Time and Tide, slow abide. A true Gamer seeks every corner, destroys every bit of crockery, and enjoys every tidbit a beautifully crafted game world can envision. To those of Water, every sense abounds with delight as the birds come alive, textures are felt, and for a time at least, you Live in the Waters of Serenia, the Winds of Spire, and the Fireswamps of Haven.

Forgive me, I'm tired and I get a touch poetic. I do hope someone reads this and replies. I love Myst and wish I could be part of the community.

Comment: I've not played Myst 4, but are there really DPS/Healer/Tank classes with Harry Potter names? That seems like a big departure for the series...

Comment: Is that answer is a mistake? Did you want to post it under another question?